# Изменение кодировки текста из файла для Python

Tags: python, html, utf-8, cp1251

Написал простой код, который должен выбирать искомые данные со скачанной веб-страницы. Однако, выяснилось, что текст страницы в неподходящей кодировке(если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно сделать текст cp1251?)

[image: Прилагаю скрин ошибки из IDLE]

Как я могу сменить кодировку средствами Python?
**Побочные вопросы:
Почему попытка создать срез строки после этого символа также приводит к ошибке?

```
Под первые ответы - прежний код имел примерно такой вид:
f = open('1.html', 'r')
a = f.read()
a = a[11: len(a)]"""Здесь уже ошибка"""
```

Comment: а сам код ??????

Comment: Скорее всего что то типа `your_data.decode("utf-8")`. Но без вашего кода это скорее теория.

Comment: Опробовано, ответ будет, что объекту не принадлежит decode

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как вы не приложили код, то просто предположу, что вам может помочь это:

```
open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') # или 'cp1251'
```

Comment: Опробовано, но open не работает с encoding согласно тексту ошибки

Comment: Благодарю за решение, моя неточность в попытках присвоить encoding переменной с текстом.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено координально, я больше не читаю из файла, а скачиваю страницу в переменную с помощью библиотеки urllib. Всем спасибо за помощь!